# Problem removing/replacing special character °

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, special-characters

I can't seem to eliminate this ° symbol.

I have tried:

```
  sed 's/°//g' file.txt
```

and

```
  sed 's/\°//g' file.txt
```

but both did not work.

I'm running ubuntu 16.

The symbol does not seem to be detected - I did copy and paste.

This did not do anything either to find the symbol

```
  sed '/°/!d' file.txt
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Already the first should work. This symbol has no special meaning, although it is a non-ascii character. No `\` is needed, don't be opportunist, if it should work without a `\`, make it working on this way! It is like you would try

```
sed 's/ő//g'
```

In such cases, the most probable reasons are:

1. Encoding problem. Check, in which encoding is the file (`file -szL file.txt`), and in which encoding are you using (`echo $LANG`). It is because the the "`°`" can have a different byte sequence in the different encodings. Best if both are in utf-8. *Extension: Ubuntu 16 is good utf-8 friendly by default, at most in the case of US-only, very old, continuously upgraded system, can I imagine such an encoding problem. It is much more realistic, that your text file is not in utf-8. The `file` command will say it to you.*
2. You may filter for a *similar* character, but not for the exact one. The are thousands of displayable characters on a not very old, utf-8 system, many of them are special hieroglyphs like this, any of them look very similar. The solution is easy also in this case: `cat` the file, and copy-paste the glyph into your command line.

If you followed these, 95% that you found and fixed the problem on this point. The remainder is for the 10% of the cases.

If none of these work, you can debug the things on the deepest byte-level. In your case I would do this:

1. I would first start this `sed` command, but I would give it the `/dev/zero` as source: `sed 's/°//g' </dev/zero >/dev/null`. This will result that the `sed` will work in an infinite loop, working on an infinite long zero-byte stream, and don't exits on the spot. So, you can debug it.
2. Suspend its execution with a ctrl/z.
3. Check for its pid with a `pidof sed`. You get an at most 5-digit integer.
4. With a `hexcat /proc/12345/cmdline` you will be able to see the byte-level data of this sed command line.
5. You can check the byte-level coding of the "`°`" by doing the same `hexcat file.txt`.
6. The two must match. If they don't, there is some evil in the picture, try (2) or ask a new question.

Many linux distros simply removed `hexcat`, one of their most useful tool, from their distrib, because they think nobody used it. But there are some other tool, as far I can remember, maybe `xxd` is one of them. If you can't make hexa dumps with anything, ask it in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Well try this easy aproach:

```
echo "°" | xxd
```

This will return something like:

```
0000000: c2b0 0a
```

You need the code **c2b0**, I guess 0a is the new line character.

Then try:

```
sed -e 's/\xc2\xb0//' file.txt
```

Hope that works.